Grease Pencil Fill Material Appearing Behind Other Objects
After much digging it appears that other objects in the scene are rendering in front of the grease pencil's fill, but not the outline.
For example, i have a grease pencil (GP) drawing of a man in an arm chair, sat in a wooden cabin. The chair is in front of his lower half, and so correctly, the chair appears in front of the GP lines + fill. However, the back wall has some holes in it, and through the holes i can see that this is where the GP fill is rendering. I turned off the walls and tested putting a cube behind my GP drawing and the fill started rendering behind the cube.
Link to a video of the issue
The normal viewport displays the stroke + fill together, the issue only occurs when I snap to camera view, or render.
Left - normal viewport, cube behind GP. Right - Camera view, cube appearing in front of fill, but not the outline.

I have tried many things, including changing the stroke to 3D world location, remaking all of my materials, re-drawing with an empty grease pencil layer, discussing with chat-gpt. No luck. The issue persists across Eevee + cycles.
This all being said, when I open a new blender file + reset to defaults, grease pencil works as expected. I am aware that i could be mashing a load of shortcuts unknowingly. Resetting preferences to factory did not change anything.
Hope someone knows what's going on here, it has caused me no end of frustration

Found the issue: My camera clipping plane was at the minimum. Moving this back to default 0.1m fixed the problem
